# multiple value(same) for a cell after refreshing/reloading jquery datatable via ajax request

Tags: jquery, datatables

after refreshing/reloading jquery datatable via ajax request when I try to see any cells data in alert box it gives multiple but same alert, after every reload the alert number increases, it looks like it is also getting value for previous ajax request. Any solution?

```
         function reload(){ 
               $.ajax({
                type: "POST",                   
                url: "../WebServices/HortalDay.aspx/GetHartalDay",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (d) {                     
                    var jObject = eval('(' + d.d + ');');                      
                    var input = {
                        "aaData": jObject,
                        "aoColumns": [{ "sTitle": "Hartal Date", "mData": "HartalDate", "sWidth": "20%" },
                            { "sTitle": "Note", "mData": "Note" },
                            { "sTitle": "Status", "mData": "Status" },

                        ],
                        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50], [10, 25, 50]],
                        "iDisplayLength": 25,
                        "bProcessing": true,
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "bPaginate": true,
                        "bdestroy": true,
                        "cache": false,
                        "aoColumnDefs": [
                            { "aTargets": [0],

                                "sType": 'date',
                                "fnRender": function(oObj) {
                                    var javascriptDate = parseDate((oObj.aData["HartalDate"]));
                                    return javascriptDate;
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    };

                }})
 $("#datatable").dataTable(input);
```

};

```
$("#btnShow").click(function(){
          reload();
var date = $('#datatable tr').filter(".row_selected").find('td:eq(0)').text());
          alert(date); 
                 });
```

Comment: everyone is watching and going.....:), please ask if the question is not clear ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the Answer. Just I had to set the windows location -

```
  $("#btnShow").click(function(){
      window.location = "../SetupUI/HortalDaySetup.aspx";
      reload();
      var date = $('#datatable tr').filter(".row_selected").find('td:eq(0)').text());
      alert(date); 
             });
```

You may find the logical explanation in this link- 
   [C# webservice calls using jQuery 1.7.1 /eval/seq/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358918/c-sharp-webservice-calls-using-jquery-1-7-1-eval-seq)